# Creating a new variable based on observations in existing variables

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am new to coding and SAS so I hope I am framing my question sufficiently. I am trying to create a new_column that indicates whether or not an observation is "VALID" in any of the variables 2-18 but " " in variable 1. I have used if then statements and it appears to work for some observations but not others. The new_column will have "yes" indicated for many rows that lack "VALID" in the var1 and have "VALID" in any of the other variables (which is the goal), but other rows with "VALID" in var1 will also have "yes" in new_column. I have shared my code below. Hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance!

```
data mydata_1;
    set mydata;
    if var2 = "VALID" 
        or var3 = "VALID" 
        or var4 = "VALID" 
        or var5 = "VALID" 
        or var6 = "VALID" 
        or var7 = "VALID" 
        or var8 = "VALID"
        or var9 = "VALID"
        or var10 = "VALID"
        or var11 = "VALID"
        or var12 = "VALID"
        or var13 = "VALID"
        or var14 = "VALID"
        or var15 = "VALID"
        or var16 = "VALID"
        or var17 = "VALID"
        or var18 = "VALID"
        and var1 = " " then new_column = "yes";
run;
```

Comment: you may need to notice the precedence of operator. try `if (var2="VALID" or ... or var18="VALID") and var1=" " then ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote the expression the AND is only between the last two comparisons. I suspect you meant the AND to be between the result of the OR across the whole series of tests for 'VALID' and the other comparison.  Add parentheses.

```
if (var2 = "VALID" 
 or var3 = "VALID" 
 or var4 = "VALID" 
...
 or var18 = "VALID")
and var1 = " "
then ...
```

Or just make it easier and use the WHICHC() function to test if VALID appears in any of the list of variables.

```
if whichc('VALID', of var2 - Var18) and var1 = ' ' then ...
```